# php compare two arrays and discard the unmatched

Tags: php, arrays

I need help to get only the paired values of this arrays:
Array `$requestedFields`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => id
    [1] => first-name
    [2] => last-name
    [3] => username
    [4] => email
    [5] => truntt
    [6] => fiff
)
```

Array `$apiFields`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => id
            [1] => id
            [2] => accounts.profile.basic
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => first-name
            [1] => fname
            [2] => accounts.profile.basic
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => last-name
            [1] => lname
            [2] => accounts.profile.basic
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => username
            [1] => username
            [2] => accounts.profile.basic
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => email
            [1] => email
            [2] => accounts.profile.emailaddress
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => test-test
            [1] => test
            [2] => accounts.profile.test
        )

)
```

I need to get the `$apiFields` elements matched with `$requestedFields` in this case only 0-4 elements values.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: use `foreach` with `in_array` that will help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the below code:

```
foreach($apiFields as $key=>$arr){
    if(!in_array($arr[0], $requestedFields)){
        unset($apiFields[$key]);
    }
}
```

It will give you the expected result in `$apiFields` array.